# LIKE Operator First Occurence Letters Fetching

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

below is the input file and I want to get the first mention of the country or region in the naming convention to build my logic in SQL. I have tried this so far but couldn't get the result.

**SQL Query:**

**select distinct email_template from table_name
where email_template like 'JP%' or email_template like '%JP'**

-- this is the query I wrote but the following lines are coming in the output but I don't need this line when it says **CN** "**CN** IS Miller College_PB_10Q1_JP_E03LO_TEM" as I have provided the like operator for JP but I can't find a way to put my logic accordingly dynamically for each of these scenario.

I don't know how to write the query dynamically where it should get the first mention of the country symbol like 'US', 'EU', 'JP' or anything. And also the places where the first two country letters starts with, means if it's JP in the beginning it should get JP, not any other country. So, how can I get that with like operator or through any other function in SQL.

```
CN IS Miller College_PB_10Q1_JP_E03LO_TEM -- this is giving 'CN' which I don't want

14Q4-AGS-SOA-EN-A-US to JP Blopetast #4(06/39/19) Email #2 -- this is giving US but I need for JP where its written first in the line

21Q2-US2JP-EN-SOA-S2R-UT-US3JP College 591 Education -- this is giving US but I need JP

09Q4-AGS-SOA- JP Q1 Ready - Email 1

21I4-IN-EPP-AT-AUUR-JPAUSG-WF-FRF-10thDec_19 -- this is giving IN but I need JP 

CN GS Sandy 2031-E3 JP -- this is giving CN but I need JP which is at the end

09Q1-AGS-SOA-EN-A3-JP #1(1/15/19) Ant Ready #3 

CNGS_16Q3_Nov_AB_1018OneOffEmail_JP -- this is giving CN but I need JP which is at the end

21Q2-CN2JP-M0M-JP_M3F-035r6-EM

Business-Email JP BP6D-ä¸
```

Comment: I don't understand. There is the string 'CN GS Sandy 2031-E3 JP' and you say you want 'JP' which is at the end. So you want the substring starting with 'JP'? And as there is nothing after 'JP' here, you want to return 'JP' only? But then you have 'CN IS Miller College_PB_10Q1_JP_E03LO_TEM'. Same situation; there is 'CP' and 'JP'. But here you say you don't want the string at all. (I would have though you'd want the substring 'JP_E03LO_TEM'.) Then you say there are strings giving you 'IN' or 'US'. How is this possible when you look for 'JP'? Aren't you getting the whole strings? Please carify.

Comment: In other words: You say "21Q2-US2JP-EN-SOA-S2R-UT-US3JP College 591 Education -- this is giving US but I need JP". No, with your query you get the whole string, because it contains 'JP'. So, what do you mean with "this is giving US"?

Comment: And what is your DBMS? When asking SQL questions, always also tag your DBMS, because the correct answer may heavily depend on it.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner - I am looking for the first mention of the country e.g., whenever the first two letters of the country appears, I want that to be categorized for that particular country. Means 1. "CN IS Miller College_PB_10Q1_JP_E03LO_TEM" - this should give me CN as it is appearing first. 2. "21I4-IN-EPP-AT-AUUR-JPAUSG-WF-FRF-10thDec_19" from this one I need to extract "IN" not JP. So, how can I write a like operator to get the first mention of countries in my sql code?

Comment: That depends on your DBMS. You need a string function that can look for the country codes' positions, so you can compare them. What DBMS are you using? (I already asked that, but you forgot to answer that question.)

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner - I am using MySQL. Can't I just simply accomplish thing using LIKE operator? What string functions I need to use? Because the data is inconsistent and I have to write a logic to make it standardize.

Comment: `LIKE` just tells you whether JP or CN or whatever *is* in the string. It doesn't tell *where* in the string it is. And yes, the inconsistent string formats are the main problem. You are looking for country codes separated from other letters by white space, minus signs, underlines and whatever. That might require a regex position function. I don't know whether MySQL features such a function. To be honest, I would write a small app reading the strings from the database and using a programming language to examine the strings instead of trying it in SQL.

Comment: I've added the MySQL tag to your request. Maybe you are lucky and some MySQL geek jumps in to help.